# How to publish Image Topic in Yolo in ROS environment? Jetson_nano_csi_cam_ros package opens up Image Topic but Yolo does not detect it

Tags: python, opencv, ros, yolo, jetson-xavier

Everything works but when it says Waiting for an Image. The process dies.
I have attached the ss.
[csi_cam launched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCtMk.png)

[Topic after launched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLLlY.png)

[Error when I run YOLO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AOoG.png)

[Launch File Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6fT0.png)

Things I am using:
Jetson Xavier Developer Kit Version
Raspberry Pi v2 Camera
ROS Melodic
YOLOv3 Github Repo from -https://github.com/leggedrobotics/darknet_ros
OpenCV - 4.1.1 compiled with Cuda - 10.2 and cuDNN - 8.0

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also,  please post the code as text and not an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.